# Jest testing context / spy on mocked variables created outside of functions (class level) Postmark

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, testing, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to do some testing in Jest but getting stuck with a mock/spy. I've managed to get the test working but only by changing my implementation (which I feel dirty about).

Here's the test:

```
import * as postmark from 'postmark';
jest.mock('postmark');

const mockGetServers = jest.fn();
const AccountClient = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    getServers: mockGetServers
  };
});
postmark.AccountClient = AccountClient;

import accountApi from './account-api';

describe('account-api', () => {
  describe('listServers', () => {
    it('calls postmark listServers', async () => {
      await accountApi.listServers();

      expect(mockGetServers).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Here's the working implementation:

```
import * as postmark from 'postmark';
const accountToken = 'some-token-number';

const listServers = async () => {
  try {
    const accountClient = postmark.AccountClient(accountToken);
    const servers = await accountClient.getServers();
    return servers;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('ERROR', e);
  }
};

export default {
  listServers
}
```

Here's the original implementation:

```
import * as postmark from 'postmark';
const accountToken = 'some-token-number';
const accountClient = postmark.AccountClient(accountToken);

const listServers = async () => {
  try {
    const servers = await accountClient.getServers();
    return servers;
  } catch (e) {
    console.log('ERROR', e);
  }
};

export default {
  listServers
}
```

The only change is where in the code the accountClient is created (either inside or outside of the listServers function). The original implementation would complete and jest would report the mock hadn't been called.

I'm stumped as to why this doesn't work to start with and guessing it's something to do with context of the mock. Am I missing something about the way jest works under the hood? As the implementation of accountApi will have more functions all using the same client it makes sense to create one for all functions rather than per function. Creating it per function doesn't sit right with me.

**What is different about the way I have created the accountClient that means the mock can be spied on in the test? Is there a way I can mock (and spy on) the object that is created at class level not at function level?**

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I missing something about the way jest works under the hood?

Two things to note:

1. ES6 `import` calls [are hoisted to the top of the current scope](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_imports-are-hoisted)
2. `babel-jest` hoists calls to `jest.mock` [to the top of their code block](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestdomockmodulename-factory-options) (above everything including any ES6 `import` calls in the block)

---

> What is different about the way I have created the accountClient that means the mock can be spied on in the test?

In both cases this runs first:

```
jest.mock('postmark');
```

...which will auto-mock the `postmark` module.

Then this runs:

```
import accountApi from './account-api';
```

In the **original implementation** this line runs:

```
const accountClient = postmark.AccountClient(accountToken);
```

...which captures the result of calling `postmark.AccountClient` and saves it in `accountClient`.  The auto-mock of `postmark` will have stubbed `AccountClient` with a mock function that returns `undefined`, so `accountClient` will be set to `undefined`.

In both cases the test code now starts running which sets up the mock for `postmark.AccountClient`.

Then during the test this line runs:

```
await accountApi.listServers();
```

In the **original implementation** that call ends up running this:

```
const servers = await accountClient.getServers();
```

...which drops to the `catch` since `accountClient` is undefined, the error is logged, and the test continues until it fails on this line:

```
expect(mockGetServers).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
```

...since `mockGetServers` was never called.

On the other hand, in the **working implementation** this runs:

```
const accountClient = postmark.AccountClient(accountToken);
const servers = await accountClient.getServers();
```

...and since `postmark` is mocked by this point it uses the mock and the test passes.

---

> Is there a way I can mock (and spy on) the object that is created at class level not at function level?

Yes.

Because the **original implementation** captures the result of calling `postmark.AccountClient` *as soon as it is imported*, you just have to make sure your mock is set up *before you import the **original implementation***.

One of the easiest ways to do that is to set up your mock with a [module factory](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options) during the call to `jest.mock` since it gets hoisted and runs first.

Here is an updated test that works with the **original implementation**:

```
import * as postmark from 'postmark';
jest.mock('postmark', () => {  // use a module factory
  const mockGetServers = jest.fn();
  const AccountClient = jest.fn(() => {
    return {
      getServers: mockGetServers  // NOTE: this returns the same mockGetServers every time
    };
  });
  return {
    AccountClient
  }
});

import accountApi from './account-api';

describe('account-api', () => {
  describe('listServers', () => {
    it('calls postmark listServers', async () => {
      await accountApi.listServers();

      const mockGetServers = postmark.AccountClient().getServers;  // get mockGetServers
      expect(mockGetServers).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);  // Success!
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Excellent answer. Understanding now. Thanks laddo @brian

Answer (score 1):

I think you might want to look at [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire).

```
import * as postmark from 'postmark';
import * as proxyquire from 'proxyquire';

jest.mock('postmark');

const mockGetServers = jest.fn();
const AccountClient = jest.fn(() => {
  return {
    getServers: mockGetServers
  };
});
postmark.AccountClient = AccountClient;

import accountApi from proxyquire('./account-api', postmark);

describe('account-api', () => {
  describe('listServers', () => {
    it('calls postmark listServers', async () => {
      await accountApi.listServers();

      expect(mockGetServers).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    });
  });
});
```

Note that I have not tested this implementation; tweaking may be required.

Comment: Thanks, proxyquire was mentioned to me, but I don't think this problem should require a further import